# My function return undefined but works well inside

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

I'm consuming a web service and i'm getting the values well, but the function it's returning undefined   :/

I've been trying to use async and await but i'm not sure about it.

```
constructor(private sessionstore: SesionStoreService, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let data:any = this.previData();
    console.log(data);
  }



  private _datosPrevision: any;

 previData() {

    this.previsiones().subscribe(data =>{
      this._datosPrevision = data;
      console.log(this._datosPrevision);
      return this._datosPrevision;
    })

  }

  previsiones():Observable<any>{
    const urlProvisiones: string = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pacientes/previsiones';

    const httpOptions2 = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': this.sessionstore.token
      })
    };
    return this.httpClient.get(urlProvisiones,httpOptions2);
  }
```

[image: Console]

I want to get the same value in both console.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As it is an asynchronous call, you can't know when it will be returned.

So if you want get the data in the **`ngOnInit()`**, move your method call inside of it.

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.previsiones().subscribe(data =>{
      this._datosPrevision = data;
      console.log(this._datosPrevision);
   })
 }
```

But I think your code seems fine (for me at least).

> **P.S:**  It is recommended to call your API within the Service than the Component.

Answer (score 1):

**The cause why you got undefined:**

```
 previData() {
    this.previsiones().subscribe(data =>{
      this._datosPrevision = data;
      console.log(this._datosPrevision);
      return this._datosPrevision;
    })
  }
```

`previData() {...}` didn't return anything and that's why undefined is assigned to data.

`this._datosPrevioson` is assigned with the `data` value and it is what you can use in your code.

```
this.previsiones().subscribe(data =>{
      this._datosPrevision = data;  
      console.log(this._datosPrevision);
      return this._datosPrevision;
})
```

**2 different ways to print data:**

What you can do is print it inside `subscribe()` (you already did). Alternatively, convert `previsiones` from observable to promise and then use `async/await`

Answer (score 0):

> **use service to get your data**

As returning data from API takes a bit time, so you need a callback from your service regarding completion of the job.

```
export class UserService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    previsiones():Observable<any>{
    const urlProvisiones: string = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pacientes/previsiones';

    const httpOptions2 = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': this.sessionstore.token
      })
    };
    return this.httpClient.get(urlProvisiones,httpOptions2);
  }
}
```

Call the function like below :

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: UserService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.previsiones()
    .subscribe( data => {  console.log(data); });
  }
}
```